# How do i edit the navigationView.xml?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm a bit new to Android and Java in general.
In the documentation no one explains how to modify the xml file of the navigation view.
In my project I display the view with a navigationLauncher, but there isn't any type of xml file inside my project.

How can I modify it?

What I want to modify is the orientation of the view in general, creating a landscape view instead of a portrait one.

Comment: Then you will need to set *your app* as landscape-oriented. The navigation view will fit to the orientation accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationLauncher` is essentially a widget that launches as an `Activity` on top of the `Activity` or `Fragment` that you have called it from. You do not have the ability to lock the orientation for this implementation.

`NavigationView` (which is eventually inflated by the `Activity` launched by `NavigationLauncher`) can also be used as a vanilla `View`.  Check out our docs on how to use this https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/navigation-ui/#navigationview